# request https makes the listener throws error NullPointerException

Tags: node.js, npm, https, request

I am trying to make an `HTTPS` request which `POST` an API request using `request` module in node.
Here is my code:

```
var request = require('request');
var post_data = {
  text: 'hello'
}

request.post({
  url: 'https://...',
  headers: {'content-type' : 'application/json'},
  body: JSON.stringify(post_data),//also tried form:JSON.stringify(post_data),
  strictSSL: false,
  rejectUnauthorized: false
},
  function (err, httpResponse, body) {
    console.log(err, body);
  });
```

The response I get is a long error message which is written in `html` which renders as the following:

[image]

This means the API server cannot find my request body. How should I fix this?

Btw, this API is tested working with Postman.

Comment: Seems like node or node.findPath("text") is null.

Comment: Try using headers of `headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},`

Comment: I think he already did in request body

Comment: Try `node.get("text").textValue()` instead.

Comment: I have no idea why someone added [tag:java]. It seems clearly unrelated to that language. I've rolled back the change. If someone sees something I don't, let me know.

Comment: It appears that *is* the response from the request. The problem is in the site you're sending the request *to*, not your code.

Comment: Thanks for your doubt. I do not have control of the API which appears to be written in Java.